# Reusable component using theme-based Box features

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to create a reusable component using Material-UI's api (not using styled-components.)  I got this far - and it almost works - but the settings that use theme variable don't work (e.g, bgcolor and padding).  Am I doing something wrong - or is this not possible?

```
  const BigPanel = styled(Box)({
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    flexgrow: 1,
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    borderRadius: 10,
    boxShadow:'1',
    p:{ xs: 4, md: 8 }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object passed to `styled` is intended to be CSS properties, but you have a mixture of CSS properties and `Box` props (`bgcolor`, `p`). Even the ones that are valid CSS properties (`display`, `width`) are **also** valid `Box` props, so the most straightforward solution is to specify all of them as props.

One way to handle this is to use [defaultProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-default-props). This makes it very easy to override some of the props when using the component by specifying them explicitly as shown in the example below.

```
import React from "react";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const BigPanel = styled(Box)({});
BigPanel.defaultProps = {
  display: "flex",
  width: "100%",
  borderRadius: 10,
  flexGrow: 1,
  bgcolor: "background.paper",
  p: { xs: 4, md: 8 },
  boxShadow: "1"
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <BigPanel>Default BigPanel</BigPanel>
      <BigPanel bgcolor="primary.main" color="primary.contrastText">
        BigPanel with explicit props
      </BigPanel>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit styled Box]

In the example above, `styled` isn't really serving any purpose anymore except to create a new component type. Though it isn't less code, below is an alternative way to get the same effect without using `styled`:

```
const BigPanel = React.forwardRef(function BigPanel(props, ref) {
  return <Box ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
BigPanel.defaultProps = {
  display: "flex",
  width: "100%",
  borderRadius: 10,
  flexGrow: 1,
  bgcolor: "background.paper",
  p: { xs: 4, md: 8 },
  boxShadow: "1"
};
```

[image: Edit styled Box (forked)]